# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using an ABPersonViewControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, addressbook, abpersonviewcontroller, addressbookui

I have an iOS app that shows a list of contact names in a UITableView, and displays a contact  with `ABPersonViewController` when a cell is tapped. This project uses ARC. If I associate an `ABPersonViewControllerDelegate` object, the app hits an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the AddressBookUI framework immediately after showing the person view:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x2403, 0x39ee15b0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
    frame #0: 0x39ee15b0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16
    frame #1: 0x319eb880 AddressBookUI`-[ABPersonViewControllerHelper notifyScrollViewDidLoad] + 64
```

Here's the `UITableViewDelegate` method (full project linked below) that shows how the `ABPersonViewController` and my `ABPersonViewControllerDelegate` (implemented as `BEVPVDelegate`) are created, associated, and presented:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ABPersonViewController *pvc = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
    BEVPVDelegate *pvDelegate = [[BEVPVDelegate alloc] init];

    pvc.displayedPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[self.contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    pvc.personViewDelegate = pvDelegate; // comment out this line to prevent the crash
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
}
```

Simply commenting out the line that sets the personViewDelegate property on the `ABPersonViewController` instance eliminates the exception, but I need this delegate object.

This is the entirety of BEVPVDelegate.m:

```
//
//  BEVPVDelegate.m
//  ABCrash
//

#import "BEVPVDelegate.h"

@implementation BEVPVDelegate

- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    NSLog(@"called");
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Here's a bare-bones project demonstrating the problem: [ABCrash.zip on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7cen1ttwjdhsqyi/t8oStLosa2)

Is there a problem in my code? Is there a workaround that allows me to use the `ABPersonViewControllerDelegate`?

Edit: I just ran the project in Instruments, and my personViewDelegate is getting released. If I create a retained property for the personViewDelegate in my UIViewController, the app doesn't crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you define the property personViewDelegate in ABPersonViewController? I think you make it weak. Just change it to strong type. The delegate object will be released after creating immediately, because weak property will not hold it. Hope it helpful.

Comment: personViewDelegate is a property on ABPersonViewController, defined by Apple, so I can't change it from weak to strong. However, I subclassed ABPersonViewController, made it conform to ABPersonViewControllerDelegate, added `self.personViewDelegate = self;` and implemented the delegate method in the subclass. That solves it.